# React Native dynamic FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make a FlatList with a dynamic number of columns which looks like this:

[image: mockup]

I'm defining the item the width and height with an item property. I have already tried a lot of things and the best working solution so far is to do it like so:

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
/>
```

You can test a working result here: https://snack.expo.io/rJWMSLzdN

The problem is that whenever rendering this list it's logging the following warning:

```
Warning: `flexWrap: `wrap`` is not supported with the `VirtualizedList` components.Consider using `numColumns` with `FlatList` instead.
```

Does anybody know how I can get the same result without any warning?
Or can I simply ignore it because it doesn't have any influence?

Comment: You can ignore it I believe, you can't use numColumns to achieve what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I tested your snack, it didn't give me any error

Comment: Yes it's only showing the error when debugging is on, as part of the YellowBox Class

Comment: I've been investigating this for a couple of hours, unfortunately @Perniferous is wrong, you should never set contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row'}} on a FlatList, this makes the screen flicker after scrolling to the about 100th item, so using FlatList like this doesn't make sense at all, I now found out that these setting: numColumns={2} and horizontal={false} have almost the same effect, it still does some crazy stuff with the margins but it somehow works. Incase someone should find a better solution, I'd be pleased to hear about it.

Comment: What about a scroll view?

Comment: My list has to be infinite